# what is difference between PUT and POST , why PUT is considered idempotent?

Tags: http, post, put

It is said everywhere[**after reading many posts**] that PUT is idempotent, means multiple requests with same inputs will produce same result as the very first request.

But, if we put same request with same inputs with POST method, then again, it will behave as PUT.

So, what is the difference in terms of Idempotent between PUT and POST.

Comment: Please cite at least one source for "put is idempotent".

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that there should be a difference between POST and PUT, not that there is any. To clarify, the POST request should ideally create a new resource, whereas PUT request should be used to update the existing one. So, a client sending two POST requests would create two resources, whereas two PUT requests wouldn't (or rather shouldn't) cause any undesirable change.

To go into more detail, idempotency means that in an isolated environment multiple requests from the same client does not have any effect on the state of the resource. If request from another client changes the state of the resource, than it does not break the idempotency principle. Although, if you really want to ensure that put request does not end up overriding the changes by another simultaneous request from different client, you should always use etags. To elaborate, put request should always supply an etag (it got from get request) of the last resource state, and only if the etag is latest the resource should be updated, otherwise 412 (Precondition Failed) status code should be raised. In case of 412, client is suppose to get the resource again, and then try the update. According to REST, this is vital to prevent race conditions.

> According to
>   W3C(http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html),
>
> 'Methods can also have the property of "idempotence" in that (**aside
>   from error or expiration issues**) the side-effects of N > 0 identical
>   requests is the same as for a single request.'

Comment: Hi ,the post is good. But, I didn't understand it. And didn't get the answer.

Comment: @Android Well, I guess I have added bit of irrelevant detail. But your answer is in paragraph one. According to REST specifications, PUT should be idempotent but not POST. There is nothing stopping you from implementing POST request in a way such that it ensures idempotency.

Comment: Good answer, but you really shouldn't cite ancient specs :-)